# Expo react-native: .png image not showing on testflight app (working fine in dev)

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight

Expo SDK version: 38

app.json includes
`"assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"]`

Styled components are used to display the image

```
const NameWrapper = styled.Image`
  height: 52px;
  width: 68px;
  margin-top: 5px;
`;

<NameWrapper source={require("../../../assets/WelcomeScreenLogo.png")} />

<WelcomeImage source={require("../../../assets/WelcomeScreen.png")}
  resizeMode="contain"
/>
```

None of these images is showing in test flight however working fine in dev mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to SDK 39 works fine.